# What happens exactly if I use a class method as an udf in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I understand whats happening if I define a Python function and use it for a PySpark UDF.

However, its not fully clear to me, what PySpark is doing when calling a method of an instantiated object like:

```
class Foo:
  _const = 1
  def f(x):
    return x +_const

foo_object = Foo()

f_udf = pyspark.functions.udf(foo_object.f)
```

How is the function brought to the executors? Does the object stay on the manager or is it copied to the executors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method call like

```
foo_object.f(x)
```

is just a syntactic sugar for

```
Foo.f(foo_object, x)
```

so effectively passing a method to `udf` is not really different from passing a plain function.

Spark will:

- Determine the closure.
- Determine the arguments.
- Serialized objects computed above as well as the called object itself.
- Distribute this bundle among the workers.

The only possible gotcha, that can encountered when you pass a plain function as well, is that serialization methods used in PySpark cannot serialize class definitions. This means that required classes have to present on `PYTHONPATH` of all workers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  What I learned practically today from testing is, that the object is copied to the executros and its "decendents" "live" there independently (ie. not sharing class variabels, not even changes to `Foo._const`).